# monotonically_increasing_id larger than total records in dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the pyspark code below.  I’m trying to create a new match_id that is sequentially increasing.  The old match_id was random unique values.  The match_id indicates matched pairs of products in the data.  So I’m sorting the original data by id.  There can be multiple id corresponding to one match_id.  I’m taking the first id for each match_id.  Then sorting that smaller dataframe of first id and match_id, by id.  Then I’m creating a new monotonically increasing id.  Then I join back to the original dataframe on match_id, so I can have the original dataframe with the new monotonically increasing match_id.  The problem that I’m having is that the new match_id is getting to values larger than the number of records in either dataframe.  How can that be possible?  Shouldn’t the new_match_id just equal the row number from id_to_match_id plus 1?  So the largest new_match_id should be 377729?  Can someone please explain what is causing these large new_match_id and suggest how I can create the new_match_id correctly?

code:

```
# partition by match_id and get first id


w2 = Window().partitionBy("match_id").orderBy(new_matched_df.id.asc())

id_to_match_id=new_matched_df\
.select(col("match_id"), first("id",True).over(w2).alias('id')).distinct()

# creating new match_id

from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id

id_to_match_id=id_to_match_id.sort('id',ascending=True).withColumn('new_match_id',(monotonically_increasing_id()+1))


new_matched_df2=new_matched_df

# replacing old match_id with new match_id
new_matched_df2=new_matched_df2.alias('a')\
.join(id_to_match_id.alias('b'),
     (col('a.match_id')==col('b.match_id')),
      how='inner'
     )\
.select(col('a.storeid'),
        col('a.product_id'),
        col('a.productname'),
        col('a.productbrand'),
        col('a.producttype'),
        col('a.productsubtype'),
        col('a.classification'),
        col('a.weight'),
        col('a.unitofmeasure'),
        col('a.id'),
        col('b.new_match_id').alias('match_id'))


id_to_match_id.sort('new_match_id',ascending=False).show()


print(new_matched_df2.count())

print(id_to_match_id.count())
```

Output:

```
+------------+------+-------------+
|    match_id|    id| new_match_id|
+------------+------+-------------+
|412316878198|864316|1709396985719|
|412316878188|864306|1709396985718|
|412316878183|864301|1709396985717|
|412316878182|864300|1709396985716|
|412316878181|864299|1709396985715|
|412316878178|864296|1709396985714|
|412316878177|864295|1709396985713|
|412316878175|864293|1709396985712|
|412316878174|864292|1709396985711|
|412316878169|864287|1709396985710|
|412316878160|864278|1709396985709|
|412316878156|864274|1709396985708|
|412316878154|864272|1709396985707|
|412316878149|864267|1709396985706|
|412316878148|864266|1709396985705|
|412316878146|864264|1709396985704|
|412316878145|864263|1709396985703|
|412316878143|864261|1709396985702|
|412316878136|864254|1709396985701|
|412316878135|864253|1709396985700|
+------------+------+-------------+


864302
377728
```

Comment: Could you provide the sample data set before these functions are applied and expected output, would be easier to understand your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi check [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) for more.

According to documentation for monotonically_increasing_id.

> The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and
>   unique, but not consecutive. The current implementation puts the
>   partition ID in the upper 31 bits, and the record number within each
>   partition in the lower 33 bits. The assumption is that the data frame
>   has less than 1 billion partitions, and each partition has less than 8
>   billion records.

what you need is something like this

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window 
from pyspark.sql import functions as 

df2 = df1.withColumn("id", fun.monotonically_increasing_id())

windowSpec = Window.orderBy("idx")

df2.withColumn("id", fun.row_number().over(windowSpec)).show()

+-----+---+
|value|id |
+-----+---+
|    1|  1|
|    3|  2|
|    9|  3|
|   13|  4|
+-----+---+
```

This will create the type of id you need.